# replace one element with another whenever it exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a script that will replace one element with another any time it exists.  This means I need to replace that element as soon as it is created, including when the page loads.

I have tried using MutationObserver to no avail.

```
var target = document.querySelector('#taskboard');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if($(mutation.target).is('div.someClass')){
            //Do a thing
        } 
  });     
});

config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true , subtree: true};

observer.observe(target, config);
```

I could obviously just check for the element every second and replace it, but I doubt that's terribly performant, and it is certainly not elegant.

How can I detect the creation or existence of an element at any time so that I may replace it with another element?

Comment: Maybe try again with the MutationObserver. There's some examples here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom) that might help.

Comment: MutationObserver is exactly what you need to use here (assuming the browsers you're targeting support it). Please add the code you tried to the question so we can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for dom changes

```
var cb = function(e){
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('watchElem');
  console.log(elems);
  // do what you need to replace the elements
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var el = document.documentElement;
      el.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', cb, false);
      el.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', cb, false);
      el.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', cb, false);
  }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to find a way to detect the element being added, but instead I found success in an approach that detects any change to the parent, then searches for the element and replaces it.  Here is a final approximation of the script:

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observeDOM = (function(){
    var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

    return function(obj, callback){
        if( MutationObserver ){
            // define a new observer
            var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
                          callback();
                   });
            }
            // have the observer observe foo for changes in children
            obs.observe( obj, { childList:true, subtree:true , attributes: true, characterData: true});
        }
})();

// Observe a specific DOM element:
observeDOM( document.getElementById('a real ID') ,function(mutations){ 

        $('a valid selector').each(function(index, element){
             bb = $.parseHTML('valid html');
             $(element).replaceWith(bb);              
        })

});
```